# Can't include file from php email pipe

Tags: php, pipe, phpbb3

I have an email pipe set up on my server that passes the body of the email to the script to process.  Part of the work the script does is cross reference data from my phpbb3 installation with the information in the email.  To do this, I include common.php, which populates a bunch of database variables.

This script has worked for ages.  It stopped working recently.  I have a suspicion that it's due to my host upgrading PHP, as I ran into other issues around the same time.  I'm not sure of this, however, since I didn't know the script wasn't running until recently.

I've reduced the problem down to the following script:

```
$myFile = "a.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, getcwd());
fclose($fh);


include('./common.php');


$myFile = "a.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, ' success!');
fclose($fh);
```

If I navigate to the script in a browser, I get the following in 'a.txt':

```
/home/mywebsite/public_html success!
```

If I run the script via the email pipe, I get the following in a.txt:

```
/home/mywebsite/public_html
```

I also get a bounced message returned:

```
  pipe to |php -q -n /home/mywebsite/public_html/theScript.php
    generated by myemail@mywebsite.com
    local delivery failed
```

I've been working on this way too long.  Hopefully someone has some insight on how to resolve this.

Comment: Try adding error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. (*if reporting is currently/potentially off*)

Comment: `./common.php` is not likely to be in whatever the script's cwd() is at the time it's executed.

Comment: Try `require('./common.php');` and see if an error is thrown.

Comment: I added the lines mentioned by Fred, and the require line by Samsquanch.  It did throw an error, but that's because I didn't take the `include` out, so it was a double include error (redefine of function).  I removed the include, and the errors went away and the same problem remains.  Marc, I thought of that, which is why you see me printing out getcwd() from both email and direct access.  They match.  That's not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out on my own.

Here's how the current script is invoked (which suddenly stopped working):
In cPanel, set an email filter to match on a subject.  Then, pipe the content to a script using the following syntax:
`php -q -n /path/to/script.php`

The script does not contain
`#!/usr/bin/php -q`
as the first line.

I suspect a PHP upgrade occurred, which made this method stop working.

I changed the pipe syntax to simply:
`/path/to/script.php`
Then I changed the first line of the script to:
`#!/usr/bin/php -q`

After this change, an email that matched my filter bounced with a different error than stated in the original question.  The new error was `permission denied`.  I changed the permissions on the PHP script to 755 and everything works again!